# Apache httpd doesn't respond to remote browser

Tags: apache-2.4, fedora-20

I installed `httpd 2.4.10-2.fc20` and it runs:

```
$ systemctl -l | grep httpd.*running
httpd.service         loaded active running   The Apache HTTP Server
```

... and listens:

```
$ netstat -pant | egrep 'PID|httpd'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address       Foreign Address     State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80          0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      29709/httpd
```

It responses as expected if accessed from a local browser on this Linux machine.

Trying to access it from FF on a Windows machine in my Intranet I get a *network timeout.* `ssh` connections (including Xming) work like a charm so it's obviously not a networking problem. I don't have a personal firewall running on this Windows that could block something.

I've seen [Apache listens, but doesn't respond](https://serverfault.com/questions/478607/apache-listens-but-doesnt-respond) but this didn't help. I disabled `iptables:`

```
$ systemctl status iptables
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

This bugs me since hours and I searched the net up and down and tried various things - to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a rule in your firewall to accept all connections incoming to port 80/tcp, try to do this:

```
 # firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
 # firewall-cmd --reload
```

Remember that the firewall service name is firewalld, if you want to disable your firewall, you need to execute the follow command:

```
# systemctl disable firewalld
# systemctl stop firewalld
```

Comment: Thx a lot! That did the trick! Is there a place with this info that I missed to find?

Comment: I think that this link will help you. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD